# postgresql and jpa: relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, annotations, mapping

Once again I'm to ask your precios help to solve a problem with Hibernate, Springboot, Postgresql.
In my project I have dozens of tables I read and write on, I've used same configuration for every tables without problems, but I'm having some problems with one of them:

This is the Class mapping my table:

```
package com.mycompany.ingestion.entities.mappingdb;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="td_titauto")
public class TdTitAuto {
    
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_td_titauto", sequenceName = "seq_td_titauto", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_td_titauto", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long idTitAuto;
    private String idAuto;
    public Long getIdTitAuto() {
        return idTitAuto;
    }
    public void setIdTitAuto(Long idTitAuto) {
        this.idTitAuto = idTitAuto;
    }
    public String getIdAuto() {
        return idAuto;
    }
    public void setIdAuto(String idAuto) {
        this.idAuto = idAuto;
    }

}
```

When I run the project, I got following error:
*ERROR: column tdtitauto0_.id_tit_auto does not exist
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "tdtitauto0_.id_titauto".*

The name of the table on DB is td_titaut. If I add the name of the schema on the annotation @Table, nothing changes, but If I remove the @Table annotation, I got the following error:

*ERROR: relation "td_tit_auto" does not exist*
In this case I have no idea why an underscore char is added (the table is named td_titauto with just one underscore).

I've tried also to use a config file instead and as well as annotation, but nothing change.
Any suggestions?
Thank you so much, I really appreciate
My best regards
Steph

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a table in your db called `td_titauto` but the default name for an entity is `td_tit_auto`. It's probably because the entity name is `TdTitAuto` instead of `TdTitauto`.

Hibernate ORM is expecting a column on the table called `id_tit_auto` but I suspect the column name in your db is instead `id_titauto`.
So, you need to change the mapping this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="td_titauto")
public class TdTitAuto {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_titauto")
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long idTitAuto;
}
```

Assuming that the name of the column with the id is `id_titauto`.

Probably, this would work as well:

```
@Entity
public class TdTitauto {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long idTitauto;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, now it works fine. Thank you so much, It was a couple of days I was fighting with this problem.

Comment: No problem, could you mark this as the right solution?